# Magento Integration with Solr

Tags: magento-2.1, api, rest-api, search, solr

I have integrated Solr with Magento EE. Solr logs whatever I search in Magento fronted search box.

I'd like to know if Magento will also use Solr engine if the search REST API is called?

**Endpoints**-

**Product Details** - `GET`- `http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/products/:sku`

**Get Category** - `GET` - `http://<magento_host>//V1/categories/:categoryId`

**General Search API** - `GET`

```
http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/products/?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_gear&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=86&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=finset
```

and the API's mentioned here
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html

Comment: Can you precise the search REST API for you ? Send me the endpoint.

Comment: @FranckGarnier Added endpoints for your reference.

Comment: For me, no these endpoints do not use the search engine.

Comment: @FranckGarnier Can you shed some more information how to check if endpoints hitting solr. Is this the default behavior of Magento endpoints even if search engine like solr installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search API is located here :

**vendor/magento/module-search/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/search" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface" method="search"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

**vendor/magento/framework/Search/Search.php**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function search(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{
    $this->requestBuilder->setRequestName($searchCriteria->getRequestName());

    $scope = $this->scopeResolver->getScope()->getId();
    $this->requestBuilder->bindDimension('scope', $scope);

    foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $filterGroup) {
        foreach ($filterGroup->getFilters() as $filter) {
            $this->addFieldToFilter($filter->getField(), $filter->getValue());
        }
    }

    $this->requestBuilder->setFrom($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage() * $searchCriteria->getPageSize());
    $this->requestBuilder->setSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());
    $request = $this->requestBuilder->create();
    $searchResponse = $this->searchEngine->search($request);

    return $this->searchResponseBuilder->build($searchResponse)
        ->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
}
```

So you can use existing search defined in the `search_request.xml` files or build your own search requests.

Example for catalogsearch used on the Magento FO : 
`vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml`

Then you can extend the SearchEngine module to add new search features such as autocomplete.

Moreover you can see that other API calls such as `/V1/products/:sku` do not use Search Engine but repository with Mysql request behind :

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/products/:sku" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function get($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false)
{
    $cacheKey = $this->getCacheKey([$editMode, $storeId]);
    if (!isset($this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey]) || $forceReload) {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();

        $productId = $this->resourceModel->getIdBySku($sku);
        if (!$productId) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested product doesn\'t exist'));
        }
        if ($editMode) {
            $product->setData('_edit_mode', true);
        }
        if ($storeId !== null) {
            $product->setData('store_id', $storeId);
        }
        $product->load($productId);
        $this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey] = $product;
        $this->instancesById[$product->getId()][$cacheKey] = $product;
    }
    return $this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey];
}
```

And by the way I recommended ElasticSearch with Magento EE.